# dealloc is being called and I am not sure why

Tags: objective-c, dealloc

I have a view with some buttons, text fields, and methods.  When I load the view, switch to another view, and then switch back, my app crashes.  I added in an `NSLog` in each method to see what the last method call before the crash was, and it was `-(void)dealloc{`

I am wondering why this method was called?  Is it called every time you reload a view?  I've double checked my code and I definitely do not call it anywhere.

---

EDIT : Found my problem, I was releasing an array that I was using to store views.  Thanks to @Darren I traced my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dealloc is called when a class is no longer needed and removed from memory.
When you have no more pointers holding onto anything in the view, then it's dealocated.

How are you switching to/from the view?

if you set a (strong) pointer to the view then it won't be dealocated automatically.

Answer (score 0):

`-dealloc` is called whenever an object's reference count drops to 0. To find your problem, figure out what object's `-dealloc` was called. What's the second method on the call stack? The third? Was `-dealloc` sent to a valid object pointer in the first place?

There are several ways to approach this sort of thing. A good first step is to turn on NSZombies (Google for it). That'll let you know if you're sending a message (like, say, `dealloc`) to an invalid object. Usually, that causes a crash, but with NSZombies you'll get a nice error message instead.

Comment: using the zombies I have found that I trying to deallocate something that has already been deallocated.  It gives me the hex value, but I am not sure where to look for this ?  (I am relatively new to Xcode).